# EXCEL: multiple condition count and data listing/summary

Tags: excel, sorting, count, vlookup, countif

I need to do a multiple condition count and data listing/summary in EXCEL.

I have an EXCEL file with the following:

```
A         B         C         D  <-- Columns
tennis    Jan 4     Smith     John
tennis    Jan 4     Fellows   Todd
tennis    Jan 4     Biebs     Justin
football  Jul 8     Smith     John
football  Jul 8     Rucker    Pete
tennis    Aug 7     Smith     John
```

etc...

I have to figure out by Last name/First Name (col D/col C), which activity they participated in (and it could be multiple times (ie - tennis on Jan 4 and Aug 7)).

I've researched VLOOKUP and countif and I can make them work on other files but I can't get them to work with this one.  I know I could sort by names and manually count but trying to figure out a way to use multiple conditions to get the answer (without having to manipulate the file too much because it is not my file in terms of who is entering the information).

Any help is appreciated (even if it requires partial manual effort!)  Anything is better than manually sorting the file multiple different ways.

Thanks!
-Dan

Comment: What results are you expecting to achieve exactly?

Comment: Do you want a list of names with each activity they participated in and then a count next to the activity?

Comment: I was just about to add a comment after continuing to dig into other examples.  I was able to create a PIVOT chart with the list of names on the left (last name, first name), activity as the header across the top with the count for each as the data (with totals on the right and the bottom).  (LET ME KNOW if that wasn't the best way to do it).

Comment: One additional item I needed to figure out was whether the student did 2 sequential activities on back to back days (or within 3 days).  So if John Smith did tennis on Jan 7 and football on Jan 9 then I know it was the same time/camp.  So basically for any participant that did more than 1 activity, check the dates and if the dates are within 3 days then let me know (as I'm writing this, I'm not sure how best it would identify it and how I would interpret it. (I may just have to manually check for those that had more than 1 activity listed?)

Comment: I created a 2nd PIVOT table and added the activity dates (made it quite messy) but then I sorted by total count of activities by participant (highest to lowest) so that will help with the manual check of the dates for now at least.  Thanks for looking into it and if you know of a way to do the date check in a more automated way, great.. otherwise finding the details on the PIVOT table have already saved me a bunch of time!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

- two extra columns in your source data. One (say wk) with `=WEEKNUM(B2)`, the other (say bod) with `=E2&", "&F2` and both copied down to suit.
- a single pivot table (the fields can be rearranged to get different 'views' and/or filtered/sorted/grouped to suit)

If you find multiple activities for the same bod for the same wk, then click on the counts that are greater than `1` and the details should help to determine whether adding a flag may be appropriate, to distinguish camps.

[image: SO19185099 example]